# ViewComponet trouble

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity

Got a problem and need some help.

This is my first model;

```
public partial class MainCategory
{
    public int MainCatId { get; set; }
    public string MainCatName { get; set; }
}
```

This is a part of my ViewComponent;

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    return View (await DBContext.MainCategories.ToListAsync());
}
```

And this is the Default.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item1 in Model)
{
    <li>@item1.MainCatName</li>
}
```

Until here all works fine and no any problem...

---

But I have one more Model, its called SubCategory;
[PS: MainCatId in MainCategory table is, related with the MainCatId in the SubCategory table.]

```
public partial class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCatId { get; set; }
    public string SubCatId { get; set; }
    public int MainCatId { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is;
To be able to list the sub categories under the related main category names.
Like this :

A Main Category

- A1 Sub category
- A2 Sub category
- A3 Sub category

B Main Category

- B1 Sub category
- B2 Sub category

C Main Category

- C1 Sub category
  ...
  ...

But I couldn't get over it.
I did try this below but its pointless.

```
@foreach (var item1 in Model)
{
        <li>@item1.MainCatName</li>

        @foreach (var item2 in Model.SubCategory.Where(x => x.MainCatId == item1.MainCatId))
        {
            <li>@item2.SubCatName</li>

        }
}
```

What shoud/could i do ?

---

EDIT :
This way it works without any error in Visual studio. It brings the page but does not return any record from the SubCategorie tables.
And yea, there are records in that table for sure.

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            return View(await ApplicationDbContext.MainCategory.ToListAsync());
        }


@model IEnumerable<ViewComponentTest.Models.MainCategory>


@foreach (var item1 in Model)
{
    <li>@item1.MainCatName</li>
    
    @foreach (var item2 in item1.SubCategories.Where(x => x.MainCatId == item1.MainCatId))
        {
            <li>@item2.SubCatName</li>
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your file and codes again,you've configured one to many relationship ：

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.AnaKat).WithMany(p => p.AltKategoris)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.AnaKatId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_AltKategori_AnaKategori");
```

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#learn-how-to-load-related-data) to learn how to load the related data(SubCategory) with MainCategory,it provided different solutions to achieve your purpose

In your View,you don't need to add the codes

```
Where(x => x.MainCatId == item1.MainCatId)
```

because the maincatId  propery of the two entities are equal by default

And If you tried nothing to load related data,the navigation property would be null as you described

Comment: Hi,@Cumhur K. I couldn't open the link accroding to the policy ,it would help if you could upload your project to github

Comment: I checked your codes,if your mouse on `Model` of you'll find it's type of IEnumerable<MainCatagory>,so it should be item1 instead of  Model  in @foreach (var item2 in Model.SubCategory.Where(x => x.MainCatId == item1.MainCatId)),hope could help

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it